# How to save application start-up and close time in text file?

Tags: c#, text, timer, charts

Just this - whlie running its showing error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

please help

what is it means? instead of that which code should I use?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Charts
{
System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private StringBuilder sb;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try {  
        this.chart1.Series["Performance"].Points.AddXY("me", 44);
        this.chart1.Series["Performance"].Points.AddXY("Year", 66);
        this.chart1.Text.Clone();
        timer1.Start();

        File.WriteAllText(String.Format(@"D:\Log at {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}.txt", DateTime.Now), sb.ToString());
     }   
    catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where timer1 is initialized??

Comment: When is `timer1_Tick` called?

Comment: it would be better if you put whole code

Comment: If you run it in the IDE under the debugger which line does the exception happen on? Which of the object is actually null?

Comment: This line showing the error `File.WriteAllText(String.Format(@"D:\Log at {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}.txt", DateTime.Now), sb.ToString());`

Comment: can anyone help me to initialize the timer?

Answer (score 0):

You have an object not initialized. Probably your StringBuilder sb or your timer.

You should have a line with something like

```
sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Comment: ok............. but still its coming like this. the time is not saving in text file.

Comment: You mean you still have the same error or just your file is not written ? Do you have write permission ? Have you tried with a simple path without spaces ?

Comment: Just try your program with a simple path first. I think your path is not supported. `File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Log.txt", sb.ToString());`

Comment: So you probably have nothing in your StringBuilder ...
You should keep track of your time and set it in your string builder.

Comment: Then how do i save date and time? in text file?

Comment: You can save it in the file name but you cannot use : as it is not allowed for a file name. 
This works just fine
`File.WriteAllText(String.Format(@"D:\Log {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss}.txt", DateTime.Now), "Test");`

Comment: `private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Hello.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            lbTimer.Items.Add(DateTime.Now);
            fs.Flush();
            sw.Close();
            
            fs.Close();

        }` its working

Answer (score 0):

timer1 must be initialized somewhere, before calling timer1.start()